# SSIS Script Task is not running code inside but not failing

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, package

I'm new in generating SSIS packages programmatically and I have an issue in one of the components that I'm generating.

I'm generating a Script Task programmatically with the code below:

```
private void EditScriptTask(ref ScriptTask pScriptTask, List<VariablesSsis> variablesSsis)
    {
        pScriptTask.ScriptProjectName = ScriptTaskProjectName;

        // Set the script language - "CSharp"
        pScriptTask.ScriptLanguage = VSTAScriptLanguages.GetDisplayName("CSharp");

        // Set variables to be used in the script task code (read and write variables)
        pScriptTask.ReadWriteVariables = ReadVariableScriptString(variablesSsis);

        // Create a new project from the template located in the default path - script task associated project
        pScriptTask.ScriptingEngine.VstaHelper.LoadNewProject(pScriptTask.ProjectTemplatePath, null, ScriptTaskProjectName);

        //Initialize the designer project, add a new code file, and build
        pScriptTask.ScriptingEngine.VstaHelper.Initalize("", true);
        pScriptTask.ScriptingEngine.VstaHelper.AddFileToProject("ScriptMain.cs", "file contents");
        pScriptTask.ScriptingEngine.VstaHelper.Build("");

        // Persist the VSTA project + binary to the task
        if (!pScriptTask.ScriptingEngine.SaveProjectToStorage())
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Save failed");
        }

        // Replace ScriptMain contents

        var contents = GetScriptMainContent();
        pScriptTask.ScriptStorage.ScriptFiles["ScriptMain.cs"] = new VSTAScriptProjectStorage.VSTAScriptFile(VSTAScriptProjectStorage.Encoding.UTF8, contents);

        // Reload the script project, build and save
        pScriptTask.ScriptingEngine.LoadProjectFromStorage();
        pScriptTask.ScriptingEngine.VstaHelper.Build("");

        //Cleanup
        pScriptTask.ScriptingEngine.DisposeVstaHelper();
    }

    private string GetScriptMainContent()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = "Va.Api.MyServiceSSIS.Infrastructure.Scripts.ScriptMain.txt";

        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        return reader.ReadToEnd();

    }
```

The package and the Script Task in it are generated with no issues but when I try to run the package in Visual Studio that's when I get the issue:

for the Script Task it seems that it runs the code inside (giving execution finished with success) but actually it doesn't.

To solve this problem I have to open the script task editor, click on "Edit Script" that opens Visual Studio and the code to be run by the Script Task, then close VS and click OK in the Script Task editor. 
If I do the above the Script Task runs the code correctly and I have no problems.

I'm using SQL Server 2014, VS 2013 (but when I open the script of the Script Task he opens the VS 2012)

Anyone had already a similar problem? Or can give me a tip?

I think it's maybe compilation problem, but theoretical in my code I'm already doing it by calling the Build method or not? (if I look at the xml code it seems like it has already hte binary code has already been built)

Thanks in advance.